# SSE support in big IP f5 load balancer

Tags: spring-boot, server-sent-events, f5, spring-cloud-gateway, big-ip

I am using SSE to push notification to client. The articture for my dataservices is as follows:

```
Client -> API Gateway(Spring cloud api gateway) -> f5(loadBalancer) -> (nginx) ->dataservice
```

When the load balancer is out of the picture, my notification works perfect but when I introduce f5 load balancer, it does not work and connection breaks.

Does f5 load balancer support long lived http connection? What configuration should I do to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear if it doesn't work at all, or if it stops working after a while (and then how long ?)

I suppose your F5 VS (*Virtual Server*) is of type *Standard*.

First, we can check if the HTTP Profile is in any way guilty. If your [Virtual Server type](https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K8082) is *Standard virtual server with Layer 7 functionality*, change it if possible to Standard by removing the HTTP Profile (and maybe some other profiles, such as caching..). You also can try *Performance Layer4* type. Is it solving the issue ? If yes, we need to identify where the problem is, probably in the HTTP Profile or in a timeout setting as described below.

Check the *HTTP Profile* configured for your VS, at the *Response Chunking* option and set it to *Preserve*. See [LTM HTTP Profile Option: Response Chunking](https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/ltm-http-profile-option-response-chunking) if you need more details.

Check both Server and Client *TCP Profiles* related to your VS, their *Time Wait* option should be *Indefinite* if you suspect a timeout issue. There are other ways to solve a timeout, I'm just giving one of them. See [K70025261](https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K70025261) if you need more details.

As you're running SSE, you should probably disable *Delayed Acks* (enabled by default) and *Nagle's Algorithm* (disabled by default), as they can make your notifications slower. They're also both at the TCP Profile screen.

Comment: Hi, with the f5 load balancer in picture, notification does not work at all. My client is angular and i am using eventsource(https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-event-source) at client side. When f5 is in picture, at client side I get error saying 'no activity within 45000 milliseconds, error connecting'. I will check the configuration you mentioned and let u know. Thanks

Comment: I don't know this package, maybe it is using websockets ? Maybe can you make a network capture (pcap file) on the client side, and post it here.

Comment: I edited my answer in order to identify the problem at the HTTP Profile or not.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question:
**YES, F5 supports SSE** as I was able to make it work with some configuration tweeks. I cannot paste the configuration snapshot here, but in summary, turning off the `**HTTP compression**` property seemed to have done the trick for my case.